# Ubuntu 18.04 and systemctl service disappearing

Tags: services, systemd

I created and enabled a service:

```
$ sudo systemctl enable /path/to/imaservice.service
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/imaservice.service → /path/to/imaservice.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/imaservice.service → /path/to/imaservice.service.
```

It exists and persists in both:

```
/etc/systemd/system/imaservice.service
/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/imaservice.service
```

I can now start/stop/status it happily. When I reboot, I can't start it. I get the following:

```
$sudo systemctl is-enabled imaservice
enabled
```

However:

```
$sudo systemctl start imaservice
Failed to start imaservice.service: Unit imaservice.service not found.
```

Every time I reboot, I have to re-enable with:

```
$sudo systemctl enable imaservice
$sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

And after this it's back to normal.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you have `imaservice.service` outside `/etc/systemd/service` in the first place?

Comment: You might be thinking of a different path? `/lib/systemd/system`?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I meant `/etc/systemd/system`. `/lib/systemd/system` is for packages. `/etc/systemd/system` is where the system administrator is supposed to keep the units they create.

Comment: Can we see the service?

Comment: You're not using an overlay file system are you?

Comment: I’m not familiar with what an overlay file system is, so I guess not.

Comment: I can share the service itself later tonight. One is for jira one for confluence, pretty basic start/stop.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Only solution that I found is to copy the service without creating links

```
sudo cp /path/to/imaservice.service /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/imaservice.service
```

In this way it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue where I could do `systemctl status` and `systemctl stop` but not `systemctl start` on a service, even though it *did start during bootup* LOL.

Problem turns out that I had a typo in one of my .service files, I was `After=network-online.service`

should have been `After=network-online.target`

though it still booted with that typo and started.

then it and dependency services started behaving like normal services.  Yikes I cannot believe systemd wasn't logging these typo issues to journalctl...